# ExpressJS res.json(data of the logged in user)

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm building and MEAN stack APP.

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
  Posts.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!post) { return res.send(404); }
    return res.json(post);    
  });
};
```

Can someone explain how can I send just the posts of the logged in user?

Note: post has a `author` key equal with the `user ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look to use the `req.user` property (I assume you're using Passport or something similar):

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
  Posts.find({author: req.user.id}, function (err, posts) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!post) { return res.send(404); }
    return res.json(posts);    
  });
};
```

If `req.user.id` doesn't work, try `console.log()` on req.user, and see if it contains the information you need.